# Minimization with the constraint that the minimum be the function of a positive odd integer

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How can I use `Minimize` with the constraint that the minimum be the function of a positive odd integer.

Say I want to minimize

```
M[l] = l
```

under the constraint of `l`is a positive integer and l is odd.

I tried this:

```
constraint = (l+1)/2 ∈ Integers
Minimize[{l, constraint}, {l}]
```

but failed with:

> Invalid constraint (1+l)/2 ∈ Integers encountered. Constraints should be equations, inequalities, or variable domain specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
Minimize[{l, l == 2 k +1 && k >= 0 && {k, l} ∈ Integers}, {l, k}]
```

> `{1, {l -> 1, k -> 0}}`

And is another.

```
Minimize[{l, l == 2 k + 1 && k >= 0}, {l, k}, Integers]
```

Both these solutions use an auxiliary variable `k` to enforce oddness.

Comment: excellent！ Now I know how to do this! thanks a lot